# Rails before destroy, calling worker, can't find record since it's been destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a `before_destroy` callback on my model named `Connection`.

It looks like this:

```
def run_my_worker
  SomeWorker.perform_async(self.id)
end
```

The method calls a Sidekiq Worker to be performed.  By the time the Sidekiq Worker is running, the model has been destroyed, and it can't "find" it when I query for it based on the `id` passed through to the worker.

How can I get around this/what are my alternatives to this situation?

Comment: Basically the choices are: (1) do the work synchronously, or (2) pass *all the data you need* to the asynchronous method (like in Reyko's answer)

Comment: 1. It's lots of resource intensive processing.  Too much to do synchronously. 2. Check my comment on his answer.

Comment: If the job still in sidekiq retries the problem will continue. Make sure you killed these jobs from scheduled and retries. The sidekiq web ui could be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the whole object which should be available to your worker even if the record gets destroyed.

```
def run_my_worker
  SomeWorker.perform_async(self)
end
```

Update 1

Parse the json then inside your worker

```
def perform(my_object)
  # parsed_object will store a hash representation of my_object
  parsed_object = JSON.parse(my_object)
end
```

Comment: The wiki specifically says **not** to  do that: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-jobs-input-small-and-simple

Comment: And even then, it serializes the object, so I would need to query for it regardless.

Comment: The wiki just warns you that the object may change state while the job is performed. In your case the object will be destroyed. The serialization of the object does not have to do with quering it but converting it into a JSON string https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/The-Basics

Comment: @Noah You could also pass in a hash with only the data you need from the model object

Comment: Not working, undefined method for Connection:String because it converts/serializes the data

Comment: @Noah Try parsing the object inside your worker as it is in JSON format

Comment: JSON::ParserError Unexpected token at '#Connection'

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approaches are:

1. do the work synchronously, or
2. pass *all the data you need* to the asynchronous method (like in Reyko's answer)

If neither of those work, you'll need to do the asynchronous work, *then* destroy the object once you're done with it.

One approach is to write a new method (like `do_whatever_then_destroy`). You can use Sidekiq's [Batches](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches) feature to get a callback when the work has completed. At this point you can destroy the model object, since you're finally done with it.